# ld: library not found for -lgsl

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to run a c code in Mac for the first time. My GSL libraries are stored in the path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include/gsl.

So, I was trying to go with: `gcc-13 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include trial.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -O3 -fopenmp`

But, it gives me an error "ld: library not found for -lgsl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
"

I am not sure how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Solved it. export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/include exports logs and solves the problem :)